# Where is the SharePoint 2013 SDK?

Tags: development, 2013, visual-studio, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I want to try out SharePoint 2013 with Visual Studio 2012.

I'm trying to locate the SharePoint 2013 SDK. Google points me to older posts about Beta SDK releases.

Visual Studio 2012 only has templates for SharePoint 2010.

Since SharePoint 2013 has been released (at least in an RTM capacity) will the SDK be available soon or does anyone know a release date?

Please note that I'm **not** looking for an answer that points to pre-release bits.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK hasn't been released yet.

Comment: From the question: "will the SDK be available soon or does anyone know a release date?"

Comment: Only the product group would know ;)

Comment: Still in preview :(

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below link. Preview SDK for SharePoint 2013

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/A/11A3D0DE-E2D1-42D8-BFF9-37DAD227BB4F/SharePoint2013PreviewSDK.msi

Answer (score 1):

The [SharePoint Developer Downloads page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/aa905690.aspx) points to the [SharePoint 2013 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30722) as well as the [Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30355). It may be useful to also review the [SharePoint 2013 Development Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj164084%28v=office.15%29) as there are significant changes in SharePoint development model.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link. SDK for SharePoint 2013
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30722

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)